# На bootstrap можно сверстать любой дизайн?

Tags: bootstrap, javascript, html, css, вёрстка

В сети пишут, что можно сверстать абсолютно любой дизайн на bootstrap. Но недавно столкнулся со сложностью верстки макета на этом фреймворке и переделывал все с нуля.

Интересно ваше мнение по теме. Bootstrap или самопис?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap -- развивающийся самодостаточный инструментарий, который идет в ногу со временем.
Любой сложный проект когда-то начинался с какого-то [**MVP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product), на котором можно узнать: нужен ли продукт. Так вот bootstrap, по-моему, достаточен для создания MVP. А если уж реализованный продукт становится востребованным, то тут пора бы подумать о самописном инструментарии.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону zurb foundation,он дает лаконичную и продуманную основу для написания чего-то своего,при этом имеет все для написания типовых проектов.